# WebGL - three.js splash-screen / scene-loading issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, splash-screen

I'm new to SOF, so sorry for running out of local habits.

// Intro: I'm trying to create a 3d model with kind of splash screen and firstpersonmovement via three.js and it's examples.

// Source: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pue3xnk0pa5sst3/wlsb.html

// Problem: Can't figure out, what's wrong in code, but can't find anything wrong. Tried to eliminate most of mistake sources, but still can't find anything.. while using chrome console to debug, no errors occur.

Any ideas?

Edit: I realized few loading sequence errors, so I actualized it. So now it's sure, that the problem is with splash screen.

Source: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nyem3z24kzgrsn9/wlsb1.html

Problem: Loaded model overdraws splash screen, can't see why..
Therefore instructions(splash screen) listener on click doesn't work and therefore it doesn't enables controls,..

Question: Why does scene overdraws splash screen?

Comment: you shouldnt add just links to dropbox, they expire and we cannot use the answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, just a small glitch in rendering sequence.